# refresh data after $_POST on same page

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, post, insert

I have a page with a  who does a post to the same page. I want that page to be refreshed with new data after a succesful database INSERT.

Let me add some code.

**default.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require("dbconfig.php");
include("head.php");

//if user is not signed in, redirect to login page
if (!isset($_SESSION['sess_user']) ) {
   header ("Location: login.php");
   exit;
 }

?>

<body>

<div id="menu">
  <?php
     include("menu.php"); //include the menu
  ?>

</div>
<div id="page_content">
   <?php 
    include ($p); //Include selection from menu.php
   ?>
</div>
?>
```

**dbconfig.php**

```
<?php 
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'someuser');  
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', 'somepassword');  
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');  
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'somedatabase'); 

$connection = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or 
die('Connection to the specified database couldn\'t be established');  
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME)  or 
die ('Specified database couldn\'t be selected');

function db_escape ($post)
{
if (is_string($post) ) {
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) {
        $post = stripslashes($post);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string ($post);
}
foreach ($post as $key => $val) {
    $post [$key] = db_escape($val);
}
return $post;
}
?>
```

**page/cities.php**

```
<?php 
//if not signed in correctly, redirect to login page
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['sess_user']) ) {
    header ("Location: login.php");
    exit;
}
?>
<h2>Available cities</h2>
<?php
//List all available cities from database
$cities_query = "SELECT city_name FROM city_selection";
$cities_result = mysql_query($cities_query);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($cities_result)) {
        echo $row['city_name'] . "<br />";
        }
?>
<?php
//Add new city to list
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $city_name = $_POST['city_name'];
    $query="INSERT into city_selection (city_name) values ('$city_name')";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
}
 ?>
<hr>
<h2>Add new city</h2>
<form method="post" action="default.php?p=settings_cities">
Namn: <input type="text" name="city_name">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add city">
</form>
```

This code may not be pretty but it works. It succesfully adds a new record to the database however I want the page/cities.php to be refreshed with my ny record after the post. Is this possible?

Let me add that this i my first ever php page. I've only read some books so don't bash me for beeing a bad programmer :)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, just move your insert part to above your select part.

**page/cities.php**

```
<?php 
//if not signed in correctly, redirect to login page
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['sess_user']) ) {
    header ("Location: login.php");
    exit;
}
//Add new city to list
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $city_name = $_POST['city_name'];
    $query="INSERT into city_selection (city_name) values ('$city_name')";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
}
?>
<h2>Available cities</h2>
<?php
//List all available cities from database
$cities_query = "SELECT city_name FROM city_selection";
$cities_result = mysql_query($cities_query);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($cities_result)) {
        echo $row['city_name'] . "<br />";
        }
?>

<hr>
<h2>Add new city</h2>
<form method="post" action="default.php?p=settings_cities">
Namn: <input type="text" name="city_name">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add city">
</form>
```

Comment: Having same issue. Perfect solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Read up on the [Post-Redirect-Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern, and redirect the browser to the same page after saving the record. The redirect should be done through PHP's [`header`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function.

As your code works now, someone refreshing through F5 will insert the same value again... P-R-G avoids this problem.

Comment: agreed, post somewhere else, and redirect back to your original page.

Answer (score 1):

You can also refresh a page with javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.location = "URL"
</script>
```

Comment: I'd go with document.location.href = "URL" - document.location is an object, document.location.href is the property that holds the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  //yada yada
```

before you do the select